# SQL - get only numbers including minus value not alphabets and character from a column

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a column which has numbers(including negative values),alphabets,alphanumeric and single character symbol(like -,&,@).

How to get rid of alphabets,alphanumeric and symbols and get the sum of the column.

I have to use the condition only in select statement not in where condition. Because it should not affect other column results.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_CSN, '^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$') THEN SUM(REMD_PART_CSN)
    ELSE NULL
END
FROM <TABLE>
```

[image: column values]

Comment: what dbms you are using?

Comment: Show what you've tried and at what point you got stuck.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: Peter This is the query 

SELECT COUNT(*),
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_CSN, '^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$')
THEN SUM(REMD_PART_CSN)
ELSE NULL  
END
FROM <TABLE>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(REMD_PART_CSN, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
                THEN CAST(REMD_PART_CSN AS NUMBER)
            ELSE 0
        END
    )
FROM yourtable
```

I.e. for every row, if `REMD_PART_CSN` looks like a number, then convert it to a number, else use `0` instead. At the end, return the sum of all those values.

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER 00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: @SelvathalapathyS How about now?

Comment: The ELSE part is not needed, SUM will ignore NULL.